# After every kernel update, debug option is first on the list at boot

Tags: fedora, kernel, boot, grub2

On Fedora 24, after every kernel update, the debug version of the latest kernel is on top of the list of kernels during boot.

Running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` fixes the list, but I currently have to run this after every upgrade.

Is there a way to fix this such that the list is properly ordered after every kernel upgrade?

[image: Boot screen after kernel update]

Comment: here is the answer for you https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10883/how-to-update-grubcfg-along-with-kernel-properly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed by itself after a few updates. I've also since upgraded to Fedora 25 and am not encountering the issue.